# Tunnel HTTP traffic from an EC2 instance to an Heroku Application

Tags: amazon-ec2, http, heroku, tunnel

We have a web application that runs perfectly on Heroku. However, that application is not available from within a given subnetwork due to firewall restriction on the Heroku IPs.

So built a simple EC2 instance with an elastic IP that works within the firewall restriction. But rather than setting up a new application to run on that instance I was thinking that we could setup some sort of HTTP tunnel on port 80 (and maybe HTTPS as well) to direct the traffic directly to the Heroku application that way we don't need to maintain a second application.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to do what I wanted using a reverse proxy with nginx.